# Stop playing sound after specified duration in milliseconds using web audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

After starting to play audio from an AudioBuffer using [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode), how do I make it stop after a predetermined time in *milliseconds*? My setup is simple:

```
// create audio source
var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

// play audio from source
source.start();
```

Using [AudioBufferSourceNode.stop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/stop) I can only specify this duration in seconds, but supplying anything non-integer will evaluate to zero for some reason, and make the audio stop *immediately*:

```
source.stop(0.25); // should be 250 milliseconds, but audio stops immediately
```

setTimeout is not precise enough, and occasional jittering/drifting occurs, especially if the UI works a lot, or other calculations are being performed elsewhere.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    source.stop(); // very inaccurate
}, 250);
```

Is there a trivial solution to stop playing an audio after a certain amount of **milliseconds**, without resorting to hacks like busy wait in a worker thread, or similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what the first argument to `stop()` does.

It represents the amount of time relative to the audio context time, which means that when calling `stop()`, you need to add that time to it:

```
source.stop(context.currentTime + 0.25);
```

Since the function accepts a double, it shouldn't be rounding it to the nearest second. According to the [Web Audio API specification](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioBufferSourceNode-stop-void-double-when):

> The when parameter describes at what time (in seconds) the sound should stop playing. It is in the same time coordinate system as the AudioContext's currentTime attribute. If 0 is passed in for this value or if the value is less than currentTime, then the sound will stop playing immediately.

Comment: _"if the value is less than currentTime"_ - that makes sense now. This solves the timing issue, however some jittering still occurs. I figured I can mute the audio source through an intermediate gainNode, and then use a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` to stop the playback afterwards, however, that will not make timing precise, at least not until I figure out if it's possible to add hardware timing to changing the gainNode's `gain.value`.

Comment: `source.stop()` should work and be very precise. If you want to use a gain node, then `gain.value.setValueAtTime(0, <time>)` should be very accurate too.